# Is there is way to remove network restriction on Google cloud SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I have an ASP.NET MVC website hosted on Godaddy, but it is not able to access the database.

I have added IP of my hosting to Google cloud SQL Server networks, but still my website is not able to connect to the database.

I am able to connect to Google cloud SQL Server from SSMS, after adding my IP to the Google cloud SQL Server instance in allowed networks.